How to fix apt update key issue?
When running sudo apt update on ubuntu 24.04 I get the following error:
Err:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/sublimehq-pub.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
W: GPG error: https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
E: The repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

How to fix that error?
Looking at the "solution" given HERE it states:
sudo mkdir -m 0755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings/

curl -fsSL https://example.com/EXAMPLE.gpg |
    sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/EXAMPLE.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/EXAMPLE.gpg] 
https://example.com/apt stable main" |
     sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/EXAMPLE.list > /dev/null

But what does this EXAMPLE.gpg looks like in my case? I see no *.gpg URL in the error output. What EXACTLY to do in my case? I am not an expert in these gpg stuff, or apt or whatever...
And what is /etc/apt/sources.list.d/EXAMPLE.list supposed to be?
I also do not need to install sublime text, it is already installed by other means. So that complete sublime text apt-install-gpg stuff can be removed, if possible...

I tried the following two commands following a google search and finding this page:
curl -fsSL https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg |     sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/sublimetext.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/sublimetext.gpg] https://download.sublimetext.com/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublimetext.list > /dev/null

but then sudo apt update has this output:
Hit:1 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease                                             
Hit:3 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease                                           
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                              
Get:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease [2,536 B]          
Ign:6 https://download.sublimetext.com/apt stable InRelease
Err:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
Err:7 https://download.sublimetext.com/apt stable Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.236.0.104 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
E: The repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com/apt stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


@guiverc That answer does not describe where to obtain the relevant EXAMPLE.gpg file. In previous versions of Ubuntu, one could pull almost any key from the central key server

Yes, that is why the linked answer is incomplete. I do not know what the "central key server" is ...

How to fix the GPG error seems clearly explained at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html#apt. Seems you were using the wrong URL to obtain the upstream GPG file. That's why it did not work.

However, since you write that you don't use that source, you have sumblime by other means that you prefer, good advice would be to simply delete that unused source.

And how to "delete" that "unused source" exactly???

After some more research I found the solution myself.
You need to check the list of sources with
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

which in my case gave the output
sublime-text.list  sublimetext.list  ubuntu.sources  ubuntu.sources.curtin.orig

So here I then removed the two files
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublimetext.list

and after that
sudo apt update

finally worked without giving an error!
